# Gaussian Blur, Mean Filter, Convolution

Tags: c, image-processing, filtering, gaussian, convolution

I want to implement a convolution function to use in mean filter and gaussian filter and I need to implement those 2 filters as well to apply to pgm files. 
I have

```
typedef struct _PGM{
int row;
int col;
int max_value;
int **matrix;
}PGM;
```

struct and

```
int convolution(int ** kernel,int ksize, PGM * image, PGM * output){

   int i, j, x, y;
   int sum;
   int data;
   int scale =ksize*ksize;
   int coeff;

 for (x=ksize/2; x<image->row-ksize/2;++x) {
  for (y=ksize/2; y<image->col-ksize/2; ++y){
     sum = 0;
    for (i=-ksize/2; i<=ksize/2; ++i){
      for (j=-ksize/2; j<=ksize/2; ++j){
        data = image->matrix[x +i][y +j];
        coeff = kernel[i+ksize/2][j+ksize/2];
        sum += data * coeff;
    }
  }
  output->matrix[x][y] = sum / scale; 
 }
}

return sum/scale;
}
```

convolution function but I get error(actually it terminates) in convolution function so I could not proceed to filter 
Can you help me with the implementation ?

Thank you.

Comment: "I get error" is not a helpful description.  What is the exact error?  What did you discover when you ran this in the debugger?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it says an access violation raised in my program but when I did the tracing I cannot get what I did wrong.

Comment: Well, what line did it crash on?  What were the values of the relevant variables at the time?  Do they appear sane?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It crashes at coeff = kernel[i+ksize/2][j+ksize/2]; line but size seem 3, i is -1 and j is -1 so coeff should be equal to kernel[0][0] I dont see the point I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure that all the pointers involved point at valid memory?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't know how to be sure actually. When I look to the addresses they point in debug they seem sane but other than that I don't know what to do

Comment: Would you provide for our perusal the code that reads in the kernel coefficients and invokes `convolution()`?

Answer (score 3):

In your convolution there are two things wrong that probably *aren't* causing the crash. The first is style: You're using `x` to iterate over the rows of an image, something I picture more as a `y` displacement, and vice-versa. The second is that when you're computing the sum, you're not resetting the variable `sum = 0` prior to evaluating the kernel (the inner two loops) for each pixel. Instead you accumulate `sum` over all pixels, probably eventually causing integer overflow. While strictly speaking this is UB and could cause a crash, it's not the issue you're facing.

If you would kindly confirm that the crash occurs on the first pixel (`x = ksize/2`, `y = ksize/2`), then since the crash occurs at the first coefficient read from the kernel, I suspect you may have passed the "wrong thing" as the `kernel`. As presented, the `kernel` is an `int**`. For a kernel size of 3x3, this means that to call this function correctly, you must have allocated on the heap or stack an array of `int*`, where you stored 3 pointers to `int` arrays with 3 coefficients each. If you instead passed a `int[3][3]` array, the convolution function will attempt to interpret the first one or two `int` in the array as a pointer to an `int` when it is not, and try to dereference it to pull in the coefficient. This will most likely cause a segfault.

I also don't know why you are returning the accumulated sum. This isn't a "traditional" output of convolution, but I surmise you were interested in the average brightness of the output image, which is legitimate; In this case you should use a separate and wider integer accumulator (`long` or `long long`) and, at the end, divide it by the number of pixels in the output.

You probably found the PGM data structure from the internet, say, [here](http://ugurkoltuk.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/an-extreme-simple-pgm-io-api/). Allow me to part with this best-practice advice. In my field (computer vision), the computer vision library of choice, OpenCV, does *not* express a matrix as an array of `row` pointers to buffers of `col` elements. Instead, a large slab of memory is allocated, in this case of size `image->row * image->col * sizeof(int)` at a minimum, but often `image->row * image->step * sizeof(int)` where `image->step` is `image->col` rounded up to the next multiple of 4 or 16. Then, only a single pointer is kept, a pointer to the base of the entire image, although an extra field (the step) has to be kept if images aren't continuous.

I would therefore rework your code thus:

```
/* Includes */
#include <stdlib.h>



/* Defines */
#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))



/* Structure */

/**
 * Mat structure.
 * 
 * Stores the number of rows and columns in the matrix, the step size
 * (number of elements to jump from one row to the next; must be larger than or
 *  equal to the number of columns), and a pointer to the first element.
 */

typedef struct Mat{
    int  rows;
    int  cols;
    int  step;
    int* data;
} Mat;



/* Functions */

/**
 * Allocation. Allocates a matrix big enough to hold rows * cols elements.
 * 
 * If a custom step size is wanted, it can be given. Otherwise, an invalid one
 * can be given (such as 0 or -1), and the step size will be chosen
 * automatically.
 * 
 * If a pointer to existing data is provided, don't bother allocating fresh
 * memory. However, in that case, rows, cols and step must all be provided and
 * must be correct.
 * 
 * @param [in] rows         The number of rows of the new Mat.
 * @param [in] cols         The number of columns of the new Mat.
 * @param [in] step         The step size of the new Mat. For newly-allocated
 *                          images (existingData == NULL), can be <= 0, in
 *                          which case a default step size is chosen; For
 *                          pre-existing data (existingData != NULL), must be
 *                          provided.
 * @param [in] existingData A pointer to existing data. If NULL, a fresh buffer
 *                          is allocated; Otherwise the given data is used as
 *                          the base pointer.
 * @return An allocated Mat structure.
 */

Mat allocMat(int rows, int cols, int step, int* existingData){
    Mat M;

    M.rows = max(rows, 0);
    M.cols = max(cols, 0);
    M.step = max(step, M.cols);

    if(rows <= 0 || cols <= 0){
        M.data = 0;
    }else if(existingData == 0){
        M.data = malloc(M.rows * M.step * sizeof(*M.data));
    }else{
        M.data = existingData;
    }

    return M;
}

/**
 * Convolution. Convolves input by the given kernel (centered) and stores
 * to output. Does not handle boundaries (i.e., in locations near the border,
 * leaves output unchanged).
 * 
 * @param [in]  input  The input image.
 * @param [in]  kern   The kernel. Both width and height must be odd.
 * @param [out] output The output image.
 * @return Average brightness of output.
 * 
 * Note: None of the image buffers may overlap with each other.
 */

int convolution(const Mat* input, const Mat* kern, Mat* output){
    int i, j, x, y;
    int coeff, data;
    int sum;
    int avg;
    long long acc = 0;

    /* Short forms of the image dimensions */
    const int iw = input ->cols, ih = input ->rows, is = input ->step;
    const int kw = kern  ->cols, kh = kern  ->rows, ks = kern  ->step;
    const int ow = output->cols, oh = output->rows, os = output->step;

    /* Kernel half-sizes and number of elements */
    const int kw2   = kw/2,        kh2 = kh/2;
    const int kelem = kw*kh;

    /* Left, right, top and bottom limits */
    const int l = kw2,
              r = max(min(iw-kw2, ow-kw2), l),
              t = kh2,
              b = max(min(ih-kh2, oh-kh2), t);

    /* Total number of pixels */
    const int totalPixels = (r-l)*(b-t);

    /* Input, kernel and output base pointers */
    const int*  iPtr = input ->data;
    const int*  kPtr = kern  ->data + kw2 + ks*kh2;
    int*        oPtr = output->data;


    /* Iterate over pixels of image */
    for(y=t; y<b; y++){
        for(x=l; x<r; x++){
            sum = 0;

            /* Iterate over elements of kernel */
            for(i=-kh2; i<=kh2; i++){
                for(j=-kw2; j<=kw2; j++){
                    data   = iPtr[j + is*i + x];
                    coeff  = kPtr[j + ks*i    ];
                    sum   += data * coeff;
                }
            }

            /* Compute average. Add to accumulator and store as output. */
            avg      = sum / kelem;
            acc     += avg;
            oPtr[x]  = avg;
        }

        /* Bump pointers by one row step. */
        iPtr += is;
        oPtr += os;
    }

    /* Compute average brightness over entire output */
    if(totalPixels == 0){
        avg = 0;
    }else{
        avg = acc/totalPixels;
    }

    /* Return average brightness */
    return avg;
}


/**
 * Main
 */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    /**
     * Coefficients of K. Binomial 3x3, separable. Unnormalized (weight = 16).
     * Step = 3.
     */

    int Kcoeff[3][3] = {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 1}};

    Mat I = allocMat(1920, 1080, 0, 0);/* FullHD 1080p:  1920x1080 */
    Mat O = allocMat(1920, 1080, 0, 0);/* FullHD 1080p:  1920x1080 */
    Mat K = allocMat(   3,    3, 3, &Kcoeff[0][0]);

    /* Fill Mat I with something.... */

    /* Convolve with K... */
    int avg = convolution(&I, &K, &O);

    /* Do something with O... */

    /* Return */
    return 0;
}
```

Reference: Years of experience in computer vision.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. I'm new in computer vision actually this is my firs try so I wasn't dealing with large images it was a 500x500 grayscale image and the user needs to enter the kernel & its size so I preferred using int ** since the size is unknown when it's created. It was supposed to return sum/scale but I edited it. I'm sending the right kernel actually I checked it while debugging. I will try to understand your code now but I want to understand what's really wrong with mine since I'm a student and I need to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Other than the issue with `sum = 0` being missing and the style issue, your code looks actually pretty good to me.

That's why I'm guessing that it has something to do with how you pass your `kernel` argument. If you are passing a `int[3][3]`, it _will_ break. If you are passing something like

    `int k1[3] = {1, 2, 1};`
    `int k2[3] = {2, 4, 2};`
    `int k3[3] = {1, 2, 1};`
    `int* K[3] = {k1, k2, k3};`
    `convolution(K, 3, image, output);`
it should work.

Comment: The code is elegant and very easy to read. Your experience certainly shows. I'll be stealing this one =)